# Running rsvars.bat before Teamcity build starts

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, c++builder

I have a **C++ Builder 2010** project that's being built using **TeamCity**. I noticed some strange errors and after reading up on them I understand that I have to set a few variables located in **rsvars.bat**. I would like the build script to execute the bat file to set up the environment before performing the actual build. How do I best accomplish this?

Can I just use a **`<exec />`** command at the very beginning of the file or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to run wrap the build in a script that calls **rsvars.bat** AND **build commands**. That would make the variables survive during the execution of the build.

But since I use *TeamCity* I like it to be a real msbuild step and not msbuild wrapped in something else. I was thinking of having the buildscript setting the variables from **rsvars.bat** into *Machine* or *User* at the start of the build and then remove them at the end, not nice though.

I finally just went with just adding the configurations to the *Build Agents* **environment configuration** in *TeamCity* and keeping installation paths identical between agents.

Comment: The last suggestion is closest... but you'd only need to do this at the build agent level if the 'paths' were different on each build agent.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new build step and then specify a custom build step order so a new build step will be the first one.

See [Configuring Build Steps](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Configuring+Build+Steps)

Comment: It does not seem to be the case that the enviroment variables set from rsvars.bat remains when the msbuild script runs. Any way to tell them to run in the same session?

Comment: Really I've not tried this myself, anyway looks like few minutes solution so please try it out [How to set envrionment variables in MSBuild file?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/0fb8d97d-513e-4d37-8528-52973f65a034/)

Comment: Each build step seems to run in a separate process and thus the variables does not survive until the second build step.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks for letting know, please let us know if you will found a solution

Comment: Added how I decided to solve it. Another note is that each **Target** within *msbuild* is also run in a separate process. This explains why a simple **<exec />** task didn't work. You could do one in each target perhaps, but that is not very nice at all :)

Comment: build steps are separate 'execs'

Comment: @John: ok, is it a problem to setup environment by launching custom batch file (rsvars.bat)?

Answer (score -1):

Add them as *Build Parameters* -> *Environment Variables* (in the build configuration), straight forward and generally works. The build parameter/environment variables will be setup automatically as environment variables on the *build agent* running the job.

You can then make a template of the build and reuse it.

Assumes that the 'paths' are the same on all **build agents**, which is generally the case. If not your suggestion of doing it by build agent is the way to go.